# git - Downloading the Android source code

Tags: android, git, cyanogenmod

I am trying to download the CyanogenMod source code (4.4.2) on a Windows PC running Ubuntu via VMPlayer.
I can use `git` and `repo` on Ubuntu with no problems, however I am looking for a way to download the source with other methods (such as torrent or zip) because I am on a slow and unstable connection and cannot get past the downloading of `android_frameworks_base`.

All suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [git archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) command with the `--remote` option could be what you are looking for.

From the git documentation :

```
--remote=<repo>
Instead of making a tar archive from the local repository, retrieve a tar archive from a remote repository.
```